# How do I create a user scenario that includes multiple pages on my website and emulates realistic user behaviour?

Tags: scripting, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

*We’ve come across this question fairly often at Load Impact, so I thought I’d add it to the Stack Overflow community to make it easier to find:*

I want my load test to be realistic. How do I create a Load Impact user scenario that emulates a realistic user behaviour, accessing different pages and also accessing some pages more frequently (for example the home page), just like real users would?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 pages on your site that users can visit, and you know how many times each page is visited by the users, you can calculate the “weight” of each page, and create a user scenario that simulates the same kind of visitor pattern on the site that real users exhibit. This is an example of how to do that.

First, we have to find out how popular each of the three pages are. This can be done by looking at statistics from e.g. Google Analytics to see how many times each page was visited the last month or so. Let’s say we have these figures:

```
==== Page ====    ==== Visits/day ====
/                 8453
/news.php         1843
/contacts.php     277
```

The total number of page visits is 10573 (8453+1843+277). If we divide each individual number by the total, we get the “weight” (percentage) for that particular page – i.e. how big the chance is that a random page load on the site happens to load that particular page:

```
==== Page ====    ==== Visits/day ====    =========== Weight ===========
/                 8453                    0.799 (79.9% of all page loads)
/news.php         1843                    0.174 (17.4% of all page loads)
/contacts.php     277                     0.026 (2.6% of all page loads)
```

Now we can create our user scenario that replicates real traffic on our site – i.e. that will exercise our web server in the same way real users do. Here is the code:

```
-- We create functions for each of the three pages. Calling one of these functions 
-- will result in the simulated client loading all the resources necessary for rendering
-- the page. I.e. the client will perform one page load of that particular page.
--
-- Main/start page
local page1 = function()
    -- First load HTML code
    http.request_batch({
        "http://test.loadimpact.com/"
    })
    -- When HTML code is done loading, start loading other resources that are
    -- referred to in the HTML code, emulating the load order a real browser uses
    http.request_batch({
        "http://test.loadimpact.com/style.css",
        "http://test.loadimpact.com/images/logo.png"
    })
end
--
-- /news.php page
local page2 = function()
    -- This example page consist of only one resource - the main HTML code for the page
    http.request_batch({
        "http://test.loadimpact.com/news.php"
    })
end
--
-- /contacts.php page
local page3 = function()
    -- This example page consist of only one resource - the main HTML code for the page
    http.request_batch({
      "http://test.loadimpact.com/contacts.php"
    })
end
--
--
-- Get a random page to load, using our page weights that we found out earlier
--
-- Generate a value in the range 0-1
local randval = math.random()
-- Find out which page to load
if randval <= 0.799 then
    -- 79.9% chance that we load page1
    page1()
elseif randval <= (0.799 + 0.174) then  
    -- 17.4% chance that page2 gets loaded
    page2()
else
    -- ...and the rest of the time (2.7%), page3 gets loaded
    page3()  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an automated web testing tool.

One option is [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). Please see the [Web Test Plan Manunal](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html) for instructions on how to create test plan for basic web site testing, including; user actions, number of users, execution speed and frequency, and data collection.

Another option for basic web scripting is [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/).

Or, if you have programming experience, I would look at using [Selenium Web Driver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp). This gives you the most flexibility, and can integrate into an existing Java, C#, Python, etc... test project. This also scales nicely and can be integrated with CI services such as [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There's also the option of recording user behaviour to create scripts for Load Impact.

Reference and instructions are here [Simulating realistic load](http://support.loadimpact.com/knowledgebase/articles/265464-simulating-realistic-load-using-load-impact)

Once recorded and possibly adapted user scenarios should go into a test configuration including how to distribute users across locations and scenarios to create a simulation as close to real world usage as possible.

Finding out how many users you should have in your test is a slightly different question and I'll defer to expand on that until actually needed.